# How to Intent from fragment to detail view?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, detailview

I have two fragments: The first one, fragment 1, includes a listview with two cases and each case has a detail view. The second fragment, fragment 2, has two images that need to be connected to fragment 1. When image 1 is clicked, I want to intent from fragment 2 and show the detail for case 1 in fragment. The code for fragments is attached below.

Is there a way to intent from fragment to detail view? Thank you.

Fragment 1

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {


public fragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

//meal list
int[] IMAGES={R.drawable.AA,R.drawable.BB};
String[] NAMES={"Case 1","Case 2"};
String[] DESCRIPTION={ "Plastic","Wood"  };

int[] IMAGES2={};
String[] NAMES2={};
String[] DESCRIPTION2={};
Toolbar toolbar;
ListView listView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle("Cases");


    toolbar=(Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Cases");

    listView=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_caselist);
    CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    TextView textView_name=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
    String casename=textView_name.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Select case:"+casename,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch(casename){
        //********add items for each case********
        case "Case1":
            IMAGES2= new int[] {R.drawable.item_1, R.drawable.item_2};
            NAMES2=new String[]{"item_1","item_2”};
    DESCRIPTION2=new String{“50”,”20”};
            OpenDetailandPassValues("Case2",IMAGES2,NAMES2);
            break;
        case "Case2":
            IMAGES2= new int[] {R.drawable.item_2, R.drawable.item_3};
            NAMES2=new String[]{"item_2","item_3”};
    DESCRIPTION2=new String{“50”,”20”};
            OpenDetailandPassValues("Case2",IMAGES2,NAMES2);
            break;
    }
}
});

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}


// pass values to activity
private void OpenDetailandPassValues(String name,int[] IMAGE2,String[] NAMES2,String[] DESCRIPTION2){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MealDetail.class);
    intent.putExtra("NAME_KEY",name);
    intent.putExtra("IMAGE",IMAGE2);
    intent.putExtra("NAME",NAMES2);
    intent.putExtra("DESP",DESCRIPTION2);
    startActivity(intent);

}

//create list
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView= getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout,null);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView textView_name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
        TextView textView_desp=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_description);

        imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES[position]);
        textView_name.setText(NAMES[position]);
        textView_desp.setText(DESCRIPTION[position]);
        return convertView;
    }
}


}
```

Fragment 2

```
public class MainPage extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


public MainPage() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    getActivity().setTitle("Main Page");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_page, container, false);
    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"snap_itc.ttf");


    ImageView ivfearless = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    ivfearless.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView ivcaptain = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image2);
    ivcaptain.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // implements your things

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.image1:
            fragment1 Fragment2=new fragment1 ();
            FragmentManager manager2=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relative_layout_for_fragment,Fragment2,Fragment2.getTag()).commit();
            break;

        case R.id.image2:
            fragment1 Fragment3=new fragment1 ();
            FragmentManager manager3=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager3.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relative_layout_for_fragment, Fragment3,Fragment3.getTag()).commit();
            break;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you learn about Parcelable objects rather than passing a bunch of single extras

Answer (score 0):

Well you can pass Bundle object in while showing Fragment. Like

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("showCase" , "Case1");
Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And then in your Fragment1, get the value of "showCase" using

```
Bundle bundle = getArguements();
String showCase = bundle.getString("showCase");
// DO as you like
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the concept of publish subscribe approach, to remove tight coupling of dependencies. You can checkout event bus,which is an Android optimized event bus that simplifies communication between Activities, Fragments, Threads, Services, etc. Less code, better quality.

Another option is to use bundles and pass them to the fragment upon creation.Even consider shared preferences for key/value pairs storage and retrieval.

Another interesting thought, would be to use obsevables from rxjava and rxandroid. Where the class containing the data can publish the data and the fragment can subscribe for data.Consider PublishSubject.

Hope this was useful :)